# Android dataBinding - @BindingAdapter custom app namespace being ignored

Tags: android, data-binding

I have created a custom bindingAdapter in android and when i pass in the color i want the color to change, this is actually for a test im working on just to make sure it works. Here is the code: 
here is my view Model for the data binding:

```
public class User {
public ObservableInt visible;

public User(int visible) {
    this.visible=new ObservableInt(visible);
}


@BindingAdapter({"app:bindColor"}) //notice the bindColor custom attribute
public static void setTextColor(TextView view,String color) {

    if("green".equals(color))
    view.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#63f421"));

}
```

}

Now in my xml file which is binded to this model im expected to pass in a color so that the setTextColor method can use it:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <data class="MainActivityBinder">
        <variable name="user" type="com.example.android.floatingactionbuttonbasic.User"/>
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_one"
            android:text="my first textview"/>

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_two"
            android:text="my second textview"
            android:visibility="@{user.visible}"
            app:bindColor="@{'green'}" //see im passing in the green string here
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

I am getting the error at runtime time of:

```
Error:(27, 65) error: package com.example.android.floatingactionbuttonbasic.databinding does not exist
Warning:Application namespace for attribute app:bindColor will be ignored.
Error:(24, 33) Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. een is missing it 
Error:Execution failed for task ':Application:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
```

if i take out the bindingAdapter stuff it works perfectly with the other databinding stuff.  Its just this custom binding thats not working. My project is titled floatingactionbuttonbasic btw.

Comment: Did you ever solved the warning also? `Warning:Application namespace for attribute app:bindColor will be ignored.`

Comment: Oh, nevermind, this guy solved it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313466/android-databinding-custom-binding-adapter-warning

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to get this to work. The issue was how i was passing in the string. It should have the `` around it.

```
app:bindColor="@{`green`}"
```

you can also do this :

```
app:bindColor='@{"green"}'
```

But what seems to not be allowed is this notation:

```
app:bindColor="@{'green'}"
```

i wrote a [blog about it](http://j2emanue.blogspot.com/2015/11/android-databinding-big-picture.html) to help others if interested.

Comment: Please mark your answer as answered, so the question doesn't appear anymore on the unanswered tab