# Android DataBinding Custom Binding Adapter Warning

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-databinding

I followed the data binding documentation for **Custom Binding Adapter** for **image loading** from official Android Developers site:
http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html

After successfully compiling the code I get a warning which is:

```
Warning:Application namespace for attribute bind:imageUrl will be ignored.
```

My Code is as follow:

```
@BindingAdapter({"bind:imageUrl"})
    public static void loadImage(final ImageView imageView, String url) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        AppController.getUniversalImageLoaderInstance().displayImage(url, imageView);
    }
```

**Why this warning is generated?**

A screenshot is also attached...[image]

Comment: Are you using the same namespace `"bind:"` in your layouts?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

I believe the namespace is truly ignored in the `BindingAdapter` annotation. The warning occurs if you use any namespace prefix, regardless of whether it matches the one used in your layout or not. If you omit the namespace, like so:

```
@BindingAdapter({"imageUrl"})
```

...the warning doesn't occur.

I suspect the warning exists to alert us the namespace is stripped off before the string is used as a key in the annotation's implementation. Which makes sense when you consider layouts are free to declare whatever namespaces they want, e.g. `app:` or `bind:` or `foo:`, and the annotation needs to work across all those cases.

Comment: Note that the `android:` namespace is the only exception: if you're setting a `BindingAdapter` for a built-in attribute such as `android:onClick`, you can include the prefix and you will not get any warning.

Answer (score 18):

Actually there are still some tutorials which add prefix to the `BindingAdapter` annotation.

#### Use `@BindingAdapter({"imageUrl"})` without any prefix.

```
<ImageView
    imageUrl="@{url}"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

#### Pro Tip

You will not get warning when using `android:` prefix in `BindingAdapter`. Because that is encouraged.
I will suggest to use `@BindingAdapter("android:src")` instead of creating a new attribute.

```
@BindingAdapter("android:src")
public static void setImageDrawable(ImageView view, Drawable drawable) {
    view.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
```

and

```
@BindingAdapter("android:src")
public static void setImageFromUrl(ImageView view, String url) {
   // load image by glide, piccaso, that you use.
}
```

**Create a new attribute only when you need it.**

Answer (score 2):

Try this, work for me!. I hope this can help you. Simple way to change image resource without binding adapter.

```
<ImageButton
        ...
        android:id="@+id/btnClick"
        android:onClick="@{viewModel::onClickImageButton}"
        android:src="@{viewModel.imageButton}" />
```

and View Model Class :

```
public ObservableField<Drawable> imageButton;
private Context context;

//Constructor
public MainVM(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    imageButton = new ObservableField<>();
    setImageButton(R.mipmap.image_default); //set image default
}

public void onClickImageButton(View view) {
    setImageButton(R.mipmap.image_change); //change image
}

private void setImageButton(@DrawableRes int resId){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        imageButton.set(context.getDrawable(resId));
    }else{
        imageButton.set(context.getResources().getDrawable(resId));
    }
}
```

Comment: `ViewModel` should not use any Android-specific classes(especially views) nor have access to `context` as that defeats the purpose of having it at the first place