# Android Studio Warn about application namespace

Tags: android, android-studio

When I compile a project in which I use `BindingAdapter`, the Android Studio always show lots of warning and jump into the source file which I write code of `BindingAdapter`.How can I solve it, I never want to show it when I compile and **also I don't want to remove the namespace app or other**, can anyone help me. Thank you!!!
 The Warning is below: [image: The Warning] 

The example source code:
[image: The example code]

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313466/android-databinding-custom-binding-adapter-warning) you just need to remove "app:" namespace.

Comment: I know this before, but I don't want to remove this application namespace. Other co-worker's android studio did not show this kind of problem.Is there any other methods to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

As @Michael Spitsin pointed out in the comment, just remove the "app:" namespace from the annotation. You can keep the "app:" namespace in your layout XML. The namespace will be removed internally unless it is `android:`; all other namespaces are treated the same.

The warning serves to inform you that the namespace does not have any effect on the annotation. So, for example, you cannot have different methods for `@BindingAdapter("app:src")` and `@BindingAdapter("foo:src")` -- the namespace is removed before it's used as a key in the implementation of that annotation. The only exception is the `android` namespace; you can have `@BindingAdapter("android:src")` and also `@BindingAdapter("app:src")` as well.

If you look through the source code that implements the `@BindingAdapter` annotation, you'll see that the namespace is removed, which is the reason for the warning. For example, in this excerpt from `android.databinding.tool.store.SetterStore.addBindingAdapter`:

```
public void addBindingAdapter(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv, String attribute,
        ExecutableElement bindingMethod, boolean takesComponent) {
    attribute = stripNamespace(attribute);
```

...you can see that the namespace is stripped, like so:

```
private static String stripNamespace(String attribute) {
    if (!attribute.startsWith("android:")) {
        int colon = attribute.indexOf(':');
        if (colon >= 0) {
            attribute = attribute.substring(colon + 1);
        }
    }
    return attribute;
}
```

This is done because that the binding adapter needs to work across any and all source files in the project, regardless of what string was used for the namespace in a particular XML file.